# Highchart -change posistion of yaxis title

Tags: jquery, highcharts

in my current project we are using Hightchart to show charts for various analysis. In `column chart` i would like to move position of title as shown in picture and there should be enough space between last observation on YAxis and YAxis title.
like As per image there should be some space between Rainfall and 250(which is last item on YAxis)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/)**

[image]

i am able to change title position but its squeezed.

[image]

As i have define chart conainer like this

```
<div id="chartBorder">
 <div id="chartContainer"  class="chartContainer">
 <div>
</div>
```

and i am not able to apply css for this please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am able to resolve this issue by using below code

```
yAxis: {
   title: {
        text: 'Some text',
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Arial'
            },
        align:'high',
        rotation:0,
        y: -5,
        offset: -50
        }
      }
```

and to set the margin  highcharts does have option called `marginTop`.

Comment: I am curious on how did you find 'high' attribute for align parameter. Cannot find it on docs.

Comment: @lvan chau http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title.align its 'yAxis.title' sorry i will updtae entire thing#

Answer (score 4):

Add following part:

```
            title: {

                "textAlign": 'right',
                "rotation": 0,
                x: 34,
                y: -140
            }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/46Ue4/

Related question: [HighCharts: How to aligned horizontal yAxis title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535624/highcharts-how-to-aligned-horizontal-yaxis-title)

Answer (score 1):

Second solution is using [renderer.text()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text)

Comment: Thanks for reply..I am able to move position of yAxis label but its kind of squeezed and not able to apply any css to this.i can play around with y but if increase the value of y i am not able to see text anymore.Please help

Comment: Thanks for you help.i was able to resolve this by using marginTop for chart.I posted same as answer.Thanks once again